# Persistent db connection in Django with multiple management commands

Tags: mysql, django

I'm wondering If i run eg. 100 management commands in a background:

```
/me/env/python manage.py mycommand --key=1
/me/env/python manage.py mycommand --key=2
/me/env/python manage.py mycommand --key=3
/me/env/python manage.py mycommand --key=4
...
/me/env/python manage.py mycommand --key=100
```

will Django use only one db-persistent connection for all commands, or creates 100 db-persistent connection (one per command)?

DB: MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Django will create and close 100 connections - one per each process.